# use jq to pull two elements from json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jq, aws-cli

I need to build a list of our AMIs. I need to get the AMI ID and the AMI Name. How can I do that in one command?

Right now I can only go:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --profile=nonprod | jq -r '.Images[].ImageId'
```

To get the AMI ID. Or I can go:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --profile=nonprod  | jq -r '.Images[].Name'
```

To get the AMI name. But is there a way to get at both elements in a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `jq`, use the (**JMESPath**) `query` option of the CLI to extract the values you want.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --query 'Images[*].[ImageId, Name]' --output text
```

Output

```
ami-12345678    MY-AMI-2018-05
ami-90123456    MY-AMI-2018-06
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, here's how to combine the two jq commands:

```
jq -r '.Images[] | (.ImageId, .Name)'
```